# Angular 2 [Stable]: Application redirected to defaulr route with Query parameters

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am working on this Angular 2 application whicg has just a single sign-in page. I used ng-cli to buuld the package and deployed the resulting package in TOMCAT.

I redirect to my angular application from another application hosted withing TOMCAT:

```
<a href= "http://localhost:8080/ta">App</a>
```

Now, I can access my Angular application just fine. The problem occurs when I send in query parameters to the Angular 2 app:

```
<a href= "http://localhost:8080/ta?aaa=bbb">App</a>
```

The moment, I go to this URL, I am taken back to 'http://localhost:8080/ta' and in the process I end up losing query parameters and I get the following error on the console:

```
error_handler.js:51Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'ta/'
Error: Cannot match any routes: 'ta/'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (apply_redirects.js:89)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (apply_redirects.js:67)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catch.js:52)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:128)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:102)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:128)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:102)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:128)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:102)
    at LastSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:128)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:468)
    at zone.js:445
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:232)
    at Object.onInvoke (ng_zone_impl.js:43)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:231)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:114)
    at zone.js:502
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:265)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone_impl.js:34)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:264)
```

Here are my routes:

```
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/ta', pathMatch: 'full'},

  { path: 'ta', component: SignInComponent   }
```

Here is how I try access my query params (which I cannot access):

```
 this.subscription = route.queryParams.subscribe(
      (param: any) => alert(param['aaa'])
       );
```

My problem is that I cannot access my query parameters. Would appreciate any pointers on this.

Comment: What Angular2 version are you using?

Comment: I am using Angular 2.0.0 Stable

Comment: Can you try the most recent Angular2.1 version and the most recent router version. It's likely that there were related fixes since then.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Sure, I'll try that. But somehow, I think this is not an issue with the version of the router. This is because, if I start the server using ng-serve (and not deploy to TOMCAT), I can very well access the query params.

Comment: I see. Perhaps this is because the server isn't configure to support HTML5 pushState.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks. I would appreciate if you could provide some  details on this can be supported. I have <base href="/"> in index.html.

Comment: That needs to be configured on the server. I don't know about TomCat

Comment: Thanks for your pointers @GünterZöchbauer. I modified <base href> tag to get this resolved.